Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на Button в Windows Form открывался сторонний документ. С++
При нажатии одной кнопки, я бы хотела, чтобы открылась не следующая форма, а конкретный документ. Если это возможно, то, пожалуйста, подскажите как этого добиться? У меня есть главная форма, где расположено три Button. Две из них ведут на две вспомогательные формы, где будут выполняться свои действия. Третья кнопка под названием "Помощь". Я бы хотела, чтобы при нажатии на нее открывался текстовый документ(Word или что-то подобное)

Ещё бы понять, что вы имеете в виду под следующей формой и конкретным документом...

У меня есть главная форма, где расположены элементы перехода на две разных формы( у каждой своя задача). Так же хотело бы добавить кнопку "помощь", при нажатии на которую будет открывать документ(Желательно Word)

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Ознакомитесь с справкой о том, как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OpenDocumentExample
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string documentPath = @"C:\path\to\your\document.docx";

            try
            {
                Process.Start(documentPath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Не удалось открыть документ: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}

Наверное как-то так?

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
